# O que é "..." em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando alguns algoritmos em JavaScript, mas estou com dúvida no seguinte código:

```
const newArray = [...arr2];
```

`arr2` é uma array qualquer composta por números, por exemplo, `arr2 = [1, 2, 3]`.

Gostaria de entender o que significa essa parte `[...arr2]` em específico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é a [sintaxe de espalhamento, ou spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Ele permite que objetos iteráveis, como arrays, strings e objetos, sejam expandidos. Talvez no exemplo da pergunta não ajude a entender bem, mas veja alguns outros exemplos:

Com essa sintaxe você pode espalhar em chamadas de funções:

```
const lista = [1, 2, 3]

function somar(a, b, c) { return a + b + c }
somar(...lista)
// 6
```

Pode espalhar em arrays, criando novos arrays:

```
const lista = [1, 2, 3]

[10, ...lista]
// [1, 2, 3, 10]

[...lista]
// [1, 2, 3]
// simplesmente copia o array

const lista2 = [4, 5, 6]
[...lista, ...lista2]
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Pode espalhar strings, que são iteráveis:

```
[...'18']
// ['1', '8']
```

E também pode espalhar em objetos:

```
const obj = {a: 1}
{...obj, b: 2}
// { a: 1, b: 2 }
```